# Grabbing Filter Options in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a several filter options in a webpage (less that $50, number of results per page, etc.) and I am trying to figure out the best way to get and store those filter option results.

I have found some examples that use something like

```
num_results = request.POST.get('num_results_dropdown')
```

to grab the value from a drop down table (or really whatever I need information from), but I am not entirely sure where to put this code or if I need to add/make changes to any other files in my project.

I don't think I need to create a form or model for the filter options because I only plan on storing the options until I have successfully sorted my results, so a lot of the tutorials I have found on grabbing information seem a little excessive for what I need.

Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML for the number of results drop down menu:

```
<select name="num_results">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
</select>
```

I haven't added any code in my python files yet to grab the options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file: views.py -- usually processed in form rendering view

```
def your_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        num_results = request.POST.get('num_results')
    #rest of the code . . .
```

Comment: Both answers helped me get things figured out, but this one helped more so that is why I am accepting it. What helped from the other answer was to use a `<form>` tag, but I ended up using `post` as my method.  It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

First point: if it's only filtering / sorting stuff, you should use a GET request ('method='GET' in your `<form>` tag).

Second point: you can obviously write your filters form manually in the template and use as many `request.GET.get("fieldname", default)` as needed in your view, but really that's what django forms are for: handling forms, whatever you do with the form's data.

Assuming what you want to do is filter a queryset, first write a form with the appropriate fields, ie:

```
class FiltersForm(forms.Form):
    PRICE_CHOICES = (
        (50, "Less than $50"),
        (100, "Less than $100"),
        (500, "Less than $500")
        )
    price = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="price",
        choices = PRICE_CHOICES,
        required=False
        )

    # etc

    def filter(self, queryset):
        if "price" in self.cleaned_data:
            price = self.cleaned_data["price"]
            queryset = queryset.filter(price__gte=price)
        # etc
        return queryset
```

Then in your view:

```
def myview(request):
    objects = MyModel.objects.all()
    form = FiltersForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        objects = form.filter(objects)

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "objects": objects,
        }
     return render(request, "mytemplate.html", context)
```

Then in your template you just have to render the form and objects...

NB1: wrt/ the objects per page part, Django has a `Paginator` class...
NB2: it can of course get much more complex, but that's the starting point.